# Android Show POI on camera

Tags: java, android, camera, augmented-reality

I'd like to show a POI on my camera which keeps its world coordinate position (as I move my camera away from the POI, the POI moves out of the camera).

I am unexperienced in this kind of programming and I need some references which I can use to implement such behavior.

Feel free to ask if you don't understand my question.
Thank you!

Comment: What have you done already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So I have already managed to get the azimuth pointing to the POI and I (obviously) have the latitude/longitude data of the POI.

I'm not sure how to continue, which framework to use or if there is already something available inside the Android SDK

Comment: So you have nothing on AR... That's a problem... I suggest you do some searching and try to choose what's suitable for you, there are a lot of materials. Here's one link that may help you get started, not sure this is the best approach for you, you decide: https://www.netguru.co/blog/augmented-reality-mobile-android

Comment: Yes, I'm a newbie to AR and quite unsure if there is a term for the problem I'm facing - I will read through the site and give you feedback if it has helped me, thank you!